# Replacement for xmltask in Gradle

Tags: ant, gradle, android-studio, xmltask

I am trying to migrate my projects from Eclipse + Ant to Android Studio + Gradle. All of them have special builds for different app stores with different tracking ids, ad ids and so on. On Eclipse I had a ant xmltask that set the values of this ids in their respective xml files. For example I had:

```
<xmltask source="res/values/admob.xml" dest="res/values/admob.xml">
<replace path="//string[@name='bottom_ad_unit_id']/text()" withText="${bottomAdUnitId}"/>
</xmltask>
```

For each store I only had to set bottomAdUnitId with the correct id and call run the task.

Is there something similar in Gradle that would allow me to do the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use [Gradle's Ant support](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html).

```
ant.taskdef(name: 'xmltask', classpath: 'path/to/xmltask.jar', classname: 'com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask') 

ant.xmltask(source: 'res/values/admob.xml', dest: 'res/values/admob.xml') {
    replace(path: '//string[@name='bottom_ad_unit_id']/text()', withText: "${bottomAdUnitId}")
}
```

Comment: That is perfect. Exactly what I needed!